# How do I compare a 200Mhz Cloud Function and a 2 vCPU Compute Engine Instance?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

How do I compare a 200Mhz Cloud Function and a 2 vCPU Compute Engine Instance? I can't seem to find information on how many Mhz does a single vCPU stands for? Or how else do I compare these values?

Answer (score 0):

You can find [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/cpu-platforms) the CPUs used by Google Cloud according to the region. And... you don't know the type of CPU that run Cloud Functions, it also depends on the region of deployment.

"200Mhz" means nothing. It depends on the CPU generation, the optimisation embedded and the computation that you perform on it (do you leverage the optimisation or not?). To compare strictly, it's almost impossible.

And, if you have 2 CPUs, that means your process can leverge multi CPU computation, that is not the case of all the apps (python in their basic form for example).

The real question is: does it enough for your workload?

*I wrote [an article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/cloud-run-performances-with-multiple-cpus-a4c2fccb5192) where I compared Cloud Run and compute Engine, if it interest you*